# Use foundation with existing styles

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have an existing legacy application. We are now planning to use Foundation and rewrite just the top bar on every page. But when I include foundation css file into the project it breaks all the existing layout due to it's css. 
One approach I was thinking is to modify foundation.css to append on a custom class to all it's selectors: Eg:
h1{}
becomes
h1.customclass{}

But I feel that this may not work since foundation js might be adding on styles internally. 
Would appreciate insight into this. Also, is there any solution to the problem of using zurb foundation with an existing application with existing styles?

UPDATE:
Finally chanced upon a solution that works: in the foundation sass files set 
include-html-classes to false to not include all foundation css classes. Then it can be selectively set to true for components which you require them for like example: for tables:
$include-html-table-classes: true;
This can allow you to not break your existing styles and selectively use foundation. Also, mixins can be used to customize even further. Eg: You can create a custom button-foundation class that is a mixin to the foundation button class and then use your custom class on buttons that you want to have foundation styles. This will not break your existing buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation is generally used for rapid prototyping at the start of projects and including it in an already mature project will cause a lot of headaches. Personally, I would just write my own or find an alternative stand alone component:

- http://exisweb.net/incredibly-useful-list-of-responsive-navigation-and-menu-patterns
- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/a-simple-responsive-mobile-first-navigation--webdesign-6074

Comment: Thanks, would something like Twitter bootstrap be usable in an already mature project?

Comment: I don't know as much about Twitter Bootstrap but it is also used for rapid prototyping so I think you could expect the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify Foundation using CSS preprocessors using SASS or Bootstrap using LESS but, if you want to remove most components using a CSS framework  loses it purpose. They include a normalize CSS component that affects all elements on DOM, even is this ones doens't have classes so even if you add different classes to all elements this would still change some parts of your CSS. Best advice here is to write your own CSS or just use other standalone components.